Get rows of previous days having same reference number appended with Rev
I have below table with payment references. I need comment for rows based on below conditions, I am using a SQL Server database.

Identify the first reversal of the payment references (e.g. 123156 and 164645 in column A) with Payment Log (465444-Reverse and 46846-Reverse), the log number is appended with 'Reverse',

Find the row which has the same payment log number recorded previously, however appended with 'Pay' like 465444-Pay and 46846-Pay.





Payment_Ref
Payment_Log
Log_Date
activity_type
Source
User
amount
credit_or_debit
Comment




123156
165151-Pay
5/10/24 619 AM
Payment
Post
Ariba
(210.72)
credit



123156
46546-Pay
5/10/24 124 PM
Payment
Post
Joelb
(10.86)
credit



123156
465444-Pay
5/10/24 125 PM
Payment
Post
Joelb
(572.57)
credit



123156
465444-Reverse
7/27/24 510 AM
Payment_Rev
Reverse
katys
572.57
debit
Joelb


123156
44465-Pay
7/27/24 513 AM
Payment
Post
katys
(22.67)
credit



123156
46846-Pay
7/27/24 514 AM
Payment
Post
Ariba
(360.10)
credit



123156
46846-Reverse
7/27/24 515 AM
Payment_Rev
Post
katys
(360.10)
credit



164645
565464-Pay
7/17/24 655 AM
Payment
Post
Ariba
(242.80)
credit



164645
565464-Reverse
7/17/24 937 PM
Payment_Rev
Reverse
Joelb
242.80
debit
Ariba


164645
454464-Pay
7/17/24 938 PM
Payment
Post
Joelb
(210.68)
credit



164645
545454-Pay
7/18/24 140 PM
Payment
Post
paula
(32.12)
credit



164645
646444-Pay
7/18/24 143 PM
Payment
Post
paula
(50.11)
credit




This query returns only data for 1st condition, but not able to apply the 2nd filter.
SELECT 
    *, 
    MIN(log_date) OVER (PARTITION BY payment_ref) AS first_rev_date, 
    COMMENT 
FROM 
    test 
WHERE 
    activity_type = 'payment_rev'

The query returns this output:



Payment_Ref
Payment_Log
Log_Date
activity_type
Source
User
amount
credit_or_debit
Comment




123156
465444-Reverse
7/27/24 510 AM
Payment_Rev
Reverse
katys
572.57
debit
Joelb


164645
565464-Reverse
7/17/24 937 PM
Payment_Rev
Reverse
Joelb
242.80
debit
Ariba



Expected output is as per below table, these are the rows linked to the first Payment_rev (column D) of payment_ref (column A)123156 and 164645 respectively, and has the same payment_log number (column B) but appended with -pay, i.e. 465444-pay and 565464-Pay.



Payment_Ref
Payment_Log
Log_Date
activity_type
Source
User
amount
credit_or_debit
Comment




123156
465444-Pay
5/10/24 125 PM
Payment
Post
Joelb
(572.57)
credit



164645
565464-Pay
7/17/24 655 AM
Payment
Post
Ariba
(242.80)
credit





expected output should contain only -pay or a combination of -pay and -reverse?


Identify first reversal for each payment_ref
Then match first reversal with the corresponding payment entry

Fiddle
WITH first_reversal AS (
    SELECT 
        Payment_Ref,
        Payment_Log,
        Log_Date,
        activity_type,
        Source,
        [User], -- 'User' is a reserved word, so we use square brackets
        amount,
        credit_or_debit,
        Comment,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Payment_Ref ORDER BY Log_Date) AS rev_rank
    FROM test
    WHERE activity_type = 'Payment_Rev' AND Payment_Log LIKE '%-Reverse'
)
-- Select the first reversal and its corresponding 'Pay' log
SELECT 
    pr.Payment_Ref,
    REPLACE(pr.Payment_Log, '-Reverse', '-Pay') AS Payment_Log,
    t.Log_Date,
    t.activity_type,
    t.Source,
    t.[User],
    t.amount,
    t.credit_or_debit,
    t.Comment
FROM first_reversal pr
JOIN test t ON pr.Payment_Ref = t.Payment_Ref
           AND REPLACE(pr.Payment_Log, '-Reverse', '-Pay') = t.Payment_Log
WHERE pr.rev_rank = 1;

Output


This can be simplified a bit using  handy  SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES Sql Server feature.

Thanks @Serg for the suggestion , I will check
